# Function to convert each number in a M..N to another number in the same range

Tags: number-theory, functions, natural-numbers

I'm trying to find a function that can convert each number (I mean natural numbers) in the range `M..N` to another number in the same range.
Later I need to convert it back.

Let's take the `0..99` range for example.
A very easy solution is:

`b = 99 - a` later to find `a` from `b`: `a = 99 - b`.
And we can be sure that `a` and `b` will be in the `0..99` range.

**What I want is the following**
If I convert all numbers from the linear series `0,1,2,3,4..99` with the function above I get `99, 98, 97, 96, 95..0`, which is another linear one.

I would like to convert `0..99` to a non-linear series, but remaining in the same range.

Something like:
0 -> 11; 1 -> 52; 2 -> 77; etc. and later convert these numbers back.

Is there a mathematical function that can do this?

**EDIT**
The function can be also an algorithm containing conditions, loops, etc. I will implement this in a programming language.

Comment: [Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good function for this is the modulo operator.

$$f(n)=an\bmod{100}$$

The choice of $a$ is up to you, but if $\gcd(a,100)=1$, then the mapping will be bijective, and the inverse function is

$$f^{-1}(n)=bn\bmod{100},$$

where $b$ is the unique integer such that $ab\equiv1\pmod{100}$. (This number can be found using the Euclidean algorithm.)

Comment: I really like this idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Write thenumbers $0,\ldots,99$ on cards, shuffle them and write down there new order. E.g. if the first three cards read $11, 52, 77$ let your first function map $0\mapsto 11$, $1\mapsto 52$, $2\mapsto 77$ and so on.
At the same time note the inverse function by writing a second table where in each row you note at which place in the seqeunce a number occured. Thus after the first three cards you will have noted $11\mapsto 0$, $52\mapsto 1$, $77\mapsto 2$.

These two arrays define functiuons that are inverse of each other as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hagen! This is a possible solution I can implement.